# where is the property 'ro.boot.verifiedbootstate' being set in Android Open Source Project?

Tags: android, kernel, android-source, init, boot

the command "**adb shell getprop ro.boot.verifiedbootstate**" is returning nothing
I need to know where this property is being set in the Android Open Source Project in order to correct that.

"**adb shell getprop ro.boot.verifiedbootstate**" must return orange , yellow or green.

Answer (score 0):

The verified boot state is set by bootloader. It's passed to Android with kernel cmdline. The verifiedboot state is appended in cmdline like "androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange". You can see the cmdline by "adb shell cat /proc/cmdline".

Android init will parse the kernel cmdline, translate the "androidboot.verifiedbootstate" to "ro.boot.verifiedbootstate".

Comment: I will check this with bootloader team